# Is it possible to dynamically add new tabs on a LWC page?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-tabset, lightning-page

I have a lightning page with a Tab component on the page. Inside of the Tab component is a LWC. The LWC is a table summary of 0 or more records. Depending on how many different records there are in the summary, I want to generate that many tabs with the singular record data. So one tab will have the summary of all of the record data and the other tabs will contain a single record's data. I am curious if this is possible to programmatically and dynamically generate a new tab with the tabs component?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to render the whole page in one lwc and bring the rendering of the tabs into the lwc component - see https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tabs/

Comment: I was thinking that would be my next best bet. thank you for confirming